# nodejs npm or google api for Travelling salesman

Tags: node.js, npm, google-api, maps, traveling-salesman

I am designing a delivery app, where the delivery boy has to handle more than 1 process(Going for delivery destinations), so I need to find the best route for
 him from the source and round trip is not required .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find many node-module implementations:

1. `node-tspsolver` ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-tspsolver))
2. `algotithmbox` ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/algorithmbox))
3. `genetic` ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/genetic))

Answer (score 1):

above options seems does not work for me for some reason. i end up using code here, it works in my cases. thanks.
https://github.com/lovasoa/salesman.js